# Retrieve nested linked data, Cakephp (2.1.0)

Tags: database, cakephp, cakephp-2.1

I have the following DB relations:

`Building hasMany Shape`

`Appartment hasOne Shape`

`Building hasMany Appartment`

`Shape belongsTo Building & Appartment`

Now, in the Shape model I would like to retrieve all shapes belonging to a certain building. This includes the shapes belonging to the appartments belonging to this certain building.

E.g.

`Building 'X'`

`There are 4 shapes directly linked to building X via the belongsTo Building relation.`
`Shape->Building`

`And there are 2 shapes directly linked to 2 appartments via the belongsTo Appartment relation. These 2 appartments again are directly linked to Building X via the belongsTo Building relation. Thus these 2 shapes are indirectly linked to building X.`
`Shape->Appartment->Building`

I can't seem to get my head around this, help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [CakePHP's Containable Behavior](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-libraries/behaviors/containable.html).

Comment: Thanks, certainly seems what I'm looking for.

Comment: It might take some reading/understanding to get used to, but - it's awesome for retrieving specific data based on associations.

Answer (score 0):

Try it with raising your [recursive value](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/retrieving-your-data.html#magic-find-types) in your find.

Comment: Not a good idea - raising recursive will do more harm than good.

Comment: Agreed when you would raise it to high. But it allready should be working when you raise the recursive to 1. However when you have many relationships defined, than the containable behavior is indeed the best choise for this situation.

Answer (score 0):

You may also want to reconsider using shape as its own table.

For example, if your table only has one properly and looks like this:

```
shapes
id     int
shape  varchar 50
```

instead do this:

```
buildings
id    int
bulding_number  int
shape varchar 50
...
appartments
id    int
appartment_number  int
shape varchar 50
...
```

It will be easier to have shape be a selectable properly on both the building and apartment table. Your database will be simpler and faster, and it will likely be easier to program.

However, if there are other properties of shape you want to capture go right ahead.

Comment: My shapes table consists out of id and coordinate_id, with a coordinates table having x and y coordinates. And a shape exists out of at least 3 x and 3 y coordinates (so 3 coordinate_id's).

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `'threaded'` clause in your `find` function.
See syntax example here: http://book.cakephp.org/1.3/view/1018/find

It will give all the dependent data in parent-child relationship